# Trouble with Django + Bootstrap3 + typeahead.js remote fetching

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-views, twitter-bootstrap-3, typeahead.js

I'm new to django and bootstrap3 and I've been trying to implement the typeahead by twitter.

my urls.py

```
url(r'^name_autocomplete/?q=$', 'home.views.name_autocomplete'),
```

my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#navPersonSearch").typeahead({
    name: 'people',
    remote: 'name_autocomplete/?q=%QUERY'
  });
});
```

my view

```
def name_autocomplete(request):
    query = request.GET.get('query','')
    if(len(query) > 0):
        print "hello"
        results = Person.objects.filter(short__istartswith=query)
        result_list = []
        for item in results:
            result_list.append(item.short)
    else:
        result_list = []

    response_text = json.dumps(result_list, separators=(',',':'))
    return HttpResponse(response_text, content_type="application/json")
```

The requests seem to be getting through from the console output:

```
[05/Oct/2013 01:34:12] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2007
[05/Oct/2013 01:34:12] "GET /static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[05/Oct/2013 01:34:12] "GET /static/bootstrap/css/typeahead.js-bootstrap.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[05/Oct/2013 01:34:12] "GET /static/bootstrap/js/typeahead.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[05/Oct/2013 01:34:15] "GET /name_autocomplete/?q=J HTTP/1.1" 200 2
[05/Oct/2013 01:34:30] "GET /name_autocomplete/?q=Jac HTTP/1.1" 200 2
```

But the typeahead isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the urlpattern as follow (you should not specify query string part):

```
url(r'^name_autocomplete/$', 'home.views.name_autocomplete'),
```

And in the view, you get `query`, while the javascript send query string as `q=`; so replace the following line:

```
query = request.GET.get('query','')
```

with

```
query = request.GET.get('q','')
```

Comment: Yes, that made the typeahead work (although it's a bit slow), but I'm unable to submit my form.

Comment: @user2027556, I think it deserve another question.

Comment: Hmm, commenting the script out allows me to submit it fine.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19195246/javascript-blocks-form-from-submitting