# javascript blocks form from submitting

Tags: javascript, html, forms, typeahead.js

I'm using Django with bootstrap3 and using twitter's typeahead.js to get autocomplete on my form.

the form:

**

```
<div id="top" class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 align="center">Home</h1>
    <h3>
        <form align="center" action="/search/" method="get" role="form">
    <input id="navPersonSearch" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search for Actor/Actress" autocomplete="off">
      </form> 
   </h3>
  </div> <!-- /.container -->
</div> <!-- /.jumbotron -->
```

**

script that handles autocomplete:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#navPersonSearch").typeahead({
    name: 'people',
    remote: 'name_autocomplete/?q=%QUERY'
  });
});

</script>
```

This form doesn't have a submit button, so you submit it with enter. Commenting out the script allows the form to submit, but with the script it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be due to typeahead modifying the keypress events; I'm not sure as I haven't worked with it. But reattaching the event might solve your problem.

try something like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#navPersonSearch").typeahead({
        name: 'people',
        remote: 'name_autocomplete/?q=%QUERY'
    }).keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            $("form").trigger('submit');
        }
    });
});
```